# Widget data: ContentProvider or SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, widget, android-contentprovider, sharedpreferences

I'm developing a widget, it needs both to store data local to the widget instance and global to all widgets (cache and common data). Currently i'm using a PreferenceActivity setting its sharedpreference file to MYAPPNAME+WIDGETID, then i store common data (4/5 vars) in MYAPPNAME prefs.

I saw a lot of examples on the net using ContentProvider for this purpose, is there any advantage? Is it faster or different in some way to sharedpreferences? Sorry but its really not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation would be, in order of, er, preference:

1. SQLite (with or without a content provider)
2. `SharedPreferences`

The reason? Transactions. `SharedPreferences` are just stored in an XML file. SQLite is transactional. I trust SQLite for data integrity a bit more than an XML file.

However, you do not need a content provider to manage data in SQLite, though you can use one if you wish.

Comment: I have no much data to save (just last update timestamp and a string loaded from internet) and im using a syncronized function to store data so integrity should not be an issue. All i need is the fastest solution, which one is the fastest/lighter in your opinion?

Comment: @JohnUopini: "im using a syncronized function to store data so integrity should not be an issue" -- you have much to learn about data integrity. "All i need is the fastest solution, which one is the fastest/lighter in your opinion?" -- neither. Write your own file, if speed is your only consideration. I recommend `SharedPreferences` only for true user settings obtained via `PreferenceActivity`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Really i dont care much about integrity if "lastupdated" value gets corrupted its not a big issue i can start over. Anyway i will use SharedPreferences for real prefs and find a fastest way to store cache (maybe a plain test file with a separator). Thanks.